# Select a member from Json

Tags: c#, json

I'm having a bit of trouble with C# (VS 2017, .Net 4.5) code. It'd be great if someone could help.
I have a Json file:

```
{
"John":{"Math":[["0.2",40]],"Chem":[["0.4",37]]},
"Jane":{"Math":[["0.3",80]],"Chem":[["0.2",40]]},
"Do":{"Math":[["0.1",55]],"Chem":[["0.1",10]]}
}
```

I would like to retrieve "0.3" and 80 values for Jane. I used these lines:

```
var source = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Data.json");
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(source); // newtonsoft.com
var list = obj.Properties().Select(x => x.Name == "Jane").First();
```

Gave error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

I altered last two lines with:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> obj = JObject.Parse(source); // newtonsoft.com
var list = obj.Select(x => (x.Name == "Jane")).First();
```

Return “False”
What should I do?

Comment: From where exactly do you expect the property `Name` to come from? It's not defined in your JSON

Comment: Why not just parse as JObject and then use `obj[“Jane”]` to get the object?

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = "{'John': {'Math': [['0.2', 40]],'Chem': [['0.4', 37]]},'Jane': {'Math': [['0.3', 80]],'Chem': [['0.2', 40]]},'Do': {'Math': [['0.1', 55]],'Chem': [['0.1', 10]]}}";


dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json); // newtonsoft.com                   


var myVal = obj["Jane"]["Math"]; //Simply you can access it by obj name !
```